# bind dynamically created controls to datatable's data

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

I have created a Form Designer application. You can see the screentshot below. The user can design a screen and save it with a name. When the user saves a form, the application just saves the control's type(textbox,label,button...), name, width,height,location x, location y and etc....

[image]

Now, I want to let user save a SQL SELECT STATEMENT into the application, then let user bind the datatable from that SQL SELECT STATEMENT to the controls created by the user.

lets say, user has saved this SELECT statement like below

```
SELECT ID,NAME, LASTNAME FROM PERSONS
```

and form created by user has 3 textboxes. How can I bind those to each other?

Can you guys give me any clue?

Comment: Where users save this sql statement? In a textbox or something?

Comment: I will make another winform screen which will have a big multiline textbox.so the user can enter even a complex select statement. I will store those select statements in DB too

Comment: As an idea, you can get this query as a string and you can check how many words between `SELECT `and `FROM`. Then you can create dynamically textboxes.

Comment: Binding Data to control requires clear indication on which control is bound to which field/column, I think this information should also be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're pulling straight from the database into individual controls, you may be able to avoid data binding and just populate your text boxes directly.

For instance, when your user-designed form initializes you could enumerate all the `TextBoxes`:

```
var textControls = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
```

Then, when you actually execute your `SELECT` statement you could dynamically populate those `TextBox` controls:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn);
    using (var rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        rdr.Read();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < rdr.FieldCount)
        {
            textControls[i].Text = rdr.GetString(i++);
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing about the above code is that it is identical for every form you create no matter how many fields or textboxes you have on your user-designed forms.

If you need to save the results back to your database, you could do a similar process when the form closes: enumerate your `TextBoxes`, build the parameters for the query string, and then execute it.

Similarly if you wanted to databind you could create a `List<>` of fields that would read the SQL data into (instead of reading it into your `TextBox` control directly). Then, enumerate the `TextBox` controls and setup data bindings with the corresponding field in the `List<>`.

Comment: Great idea. But I want to let user select FieldName from a combobox which will belong to each textbox. Because user might have a select statemen with 10 columns and 5 textboxes. Therefore, I want him to set TextBox's fieldname by selecting from a combobox.. does it make sense?

Comment: @ayilmaz, sure and that might not be that different as you probably have a list of mappings (which field goes to which textbox) that you could use to 1) find the right text box and 2) populate the correct field from the result set.